# PHP Parse Error - Unexpected End of File

Tags: php, unexpectendoffile

I'm a complete newbie to programming and php, my code's throwing back an error saying there's an unexpected end to the file and I can't for the life of me see what's missing or there that shouldn't be. Can anyone spot it?

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'s Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['username'])){
  $username = $_GET['username'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die ("Could not connect to the server");
    mysql_select_db("users") or die ("That database could not be found.");
 $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ("The query could not be completed, please try again later.");
 if(mysql_num_rows($userquery) !=1){
  die ("That user could not be found.");
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
  $lastname = $row['lastname'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $dbusername = $row['dbusername'];
  $access = $row['access'];
  }
  if($username != $dbusername){
   die ("There has been a fatal error, please try again.");  
  }
 
  if($access == 1) {
   $access = "Level 1 User";
  } else 
   if($access == 2) {
    $access = "Level 2 User";
   } else 
     if($access == 3) {
      $access = "Level 3 User";
     } else 
      if($access == 4) {
       $access = "Administrator.";
      } else die ("This user has an access level beyond the realms of possibility. Beware.");
 
     

?>

<h2><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'s Profile</h2><br />
<table>
 <tr><td>Firstname:</td><td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lastname:</td><td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email:</td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>dbusername:</td><td><?php echo $dbusername; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>access:</td><td><?php echo $access; ?></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where does your WHILE loop ends?

Answer (score 0):

Is the main if code block that needs to be closed with a }

```html
<html>
<head>
<title><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'s Profile</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

if (isset($_GET['username'])){
  $username = $_GET['username'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root", "") or die ("Could not connect to the server");
    mysql_select_db("users") or die ("That database could not be found.");
 $userquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'") or die ("The query could not be completed, please try again later.");
 if(mysql_num_rows($userquery) !=1){
  die ("That user could not be found.");
 }
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($userquery, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
  $firstname = $row['firstname'];
  $lastname = $row['lastname'];
  $email = $row['email'];
  $dbusername = $row['dbusername'];
  $access = $row['access'];
  }
  if($username != $dbusername){
   die ("There has been a fatal error, please try again.");  
  }
 
  if($access == 1) {
   $access = "Level 1 User";
  } else 
   if($access == 2) {
    $access = "Level 2 User";
   } else 
     if($access == 3) {
      $access = "Level 3 User";
     } else 
      if($access == 4) {
       $access = "Administrator.";
      } else die ("This user has an access level beyond the realms of possibility. Beware.");
}//THIS IS WHAT IS MISSING
     

?>

<h2><?php echo $firstname; ?> <?php echo $lastname; ?>'s Profile</h2><br />
<table>
 <tr><td>Firstname:</td><td><?php echo $firstname; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Lastname:</td><td><?php echo $lastname; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td>email:</td><td><?php echo $email; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>dbusername:</td><td><?php echo $dbusername; ?></td></tr>
 <tr><td>access:</td><td><?php echo $access; ?></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling it was in that area but I just couldn't spot it.